# Xcode: NSMutableArray not able to have more than 3 entries

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I need some help with handling the content of my UITableView. 
I already looked up every question containing the problems I am troubling with, but not a single one gave me a solution.

Basic information: 
**UITableViewController** with *static cells* (with several TextFields, etc.
One static cell contains another **TableView** which has dynamic cells (handled from the **UITableViewController**).
At the end of the dynamic TableView there is a button. The button calls an UIAlertController with textInput. The textInput is added to an array, which is the dataSource of the dynamic tableView.
For the first 3 entries, everything just works fine and the Tableview displays the entered text. As soon as I get to the 4th Entry (Index 3 in the Array) giving me this error:       `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`

Code **loading the Array** at viewDidLoad:

```
serialnumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:30];
serialnumbers = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[_artikelInfos valueForKey:@"checks"]];
```

Code of the UIAlertController:

```
UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSString *serialnumber = [[firstAlert textFields] lastObject].text;
        [serialnumbers addObject:serialnumber];
        NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:serialnumbers];
        [_artikelInfos setValue:arrayData forKey:@"checks"];
        [context save:nil];
        [_dynamicTableView reloadData];
    }];
```

A already had the same Problem in another TableView with the same structure where I simply limited the maximum numberOfRows to 3 (this is not the best solution, but the tableView was connected to a searchBar, so there was no need to display more than 3 entries when loading the view).

Thank You!

Comment: Try adding exception breakpoints and show at which line does the app crash

Comment: can you please print serialnumber after add in array in UIAlertAction and again print _artikelInfos this and tell me what is the different between both output.

Comment: While the exact cause of your issue is not immediately obvious it might help you to track it down if you figure out why the very first line of code you show above is completely pointless in that context. It that mistake is due to some misunderstanding on your part, correcting that may help you discover the error you report. HTH

Comment: serialnumber exactly shows the input of the textField in the UIAlertController. The array serialnumbers printed after adding another entry also shows the correct array with 4 entries.

Comment: What confuses me is the fact that I don't use any NSArray in that code, only NSMutableArray. So the error with NSArrayI cannot be related to the arrays created by me (I tried accessing the 20th index of the Mutable Array), because if it was an error with this array, the error would call on the NSArrayM Object.

Comment: I suggest it has something to do with the tableview copying the array to adopt the layout of the cells.